# iphone apns sending push notification in different languages with voice

Tags: php, iphone

i have studied and implemented Ray wenderlich's awesome tutorials on apns, and i am using this php script on server side

https://github.com/sebastianborggrewe/PHP-Apple-Push-Notification-Server

every thing is going well, but i just want to know that how can i send push notification in a language other than english, like arabic, urdu, hindi or french...???(i am sending notifications from php server using a web form) this is first part of question, the other part is that can i send a voice message with push notification, i know that there is a property for sound in apns but dont know its max. length (max length of push notification is 256 bytes). plz. guide me thanx and Regards Saad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sound support is limited to playing audio files of the app (you include PushSound.aiff in your app and send "PushSound.aiff" in your apns-message.. that's all you can do!)

For localization, you [need to include localized strings in your app and then include the String-Key(ID) in the push message.

You should read the [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/StringsFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000005-SW1) apple provides for all questions regarding push notifications

To add localized strings, you can add a strings file (file->new, select iOS/Resource->Stringsfile; name it Localizable.strings). You can add format strings ("%@ has sent you a new message") and supply the format string's arguments in the push notification (see [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/StringsFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000005-SW1)).
Again there is a [internationalization guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW21)

Comment: Thanx martin i will read the guide also but can u explain a little about that String-Key(ID) and also about including localized string in the app plz and also is there any tutorial around for this.

Comment: in ios/Resource there is no option for Stringsfile, this option is present in Mac osx/Resource, and also i am sending push notification from php side not from app.

Comment: i am using xcode 3.2.5, is that the reason, i cant see the Strings file in ios/Resource, and what could be its solution.

Comment: it's a different menu system but it should be somewhere under file->new. if you seriously want to develop an app for the store you will need to upgrade..